# Before Vocaloid -- Early history of voice synthesis?

Tags: voice, history, synthesizer

[Vocaloid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocaloid) is a modern musical voice synthesiser package from Japan. It's getting pretty close to a human voice: Compare [GUMI (Vocaloid)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LYwB9Lr4Two) and [Megumi Nakajima (GUMI's voice sample provider; human)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FueivoYAx8Q) singing the same song!

All this amazing technology had to start somewhere! I wonder, **what is the early history of *musical* voice synthesisers?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daisy_Bell):

> In 1961, the IBM 7094 became the first computer to sing, singing the song Daisy Bell. Vocals were programmed by John Kelly and Carol Lochbaum and the accompaniment was programmed by Max Mathews. This performance was the inspiration for the famous scene in the 1968 film 2001: A Space Odyssey in which the HAL 9000 computer sings the song as it is deactivated.

A captured video of the IBM7094 singing can be found on [Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_atvrjrTekY) as well.

I found it quite amusing :). (And 'Daisy Bell' is now stuck in my head for the rest of the day...)

Comment: Interesting! I found a video with Vocaloid singing the same song: http://youtu.be/0-llejuqVik :D